# Are Lie algebra representations $\rho$ and $\rho\circ F$ isomorphic?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $F: \mathfrak g \to \mathfrak g$ be a Lie algebra automorphism, and let $\rho: \mathfrak g \to GL(V)$ be a representation.

Question: Are $\rho$ and $\rho \circ F$ isomorphic?

Motivation: This question is motivated from the physics literature. Physicists often deal with 2nd quantization formalism (where operators can be thought of as elements of a Lie algebra), and they sometimes employ transformations on these operators that preserve the commutation relations. Then, they (maybe naively) use the transformed operators. When I carefully examine these arguments, there is a gap which is precisely stated by my question.

Comment: This is true if $F$ is an *inner* automorphism (i.e. comes from conjugating by an element of the Lie group $G$ acting on $\frak g$ with the so-called adjoint representation), but not otherwise for "outer" automorphisms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, these representations are *not* equivalent.

Example: Let $\mathfrak g := \mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb C)$ and $F: X \mapsto -X^{tr}$. Let $\rho: \mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb C) \subset \mathfrak{gl}_3(\mathbb C)$ the standard representation. Then it is an exercise to check that there is no $A \in M_3(\mathbb C)$ such that $F(X) = AXA^{-1}$ for all $X\in \mathfrak g$, i.e. the representations $\rho$ and $\rho \circ F$ are not equivalent.

---

However, note the following which might redeem the approach: An isomorphism of Lie algebras $F: \mathfrak g_1 \stackrel{\simeq}\rightarrow \mathfrak g_2$ does induce an [equivalence of categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories) between (say, finite-dimensional complex) representations of $\mathfrak g_1$ and (finite-dimensional complex) representations of $\mathfrak g_2$ via

$$ Rep (\mathfrak g_2) \rightarrow Rep(\mathfrak g_1)$$

$$ (\rho, V) \mapsto (\rho \circ F, V).$$

In particular, any *auto*morphism $F: \mathfrak g \rightarrow \mathfrak g$ induces an *auto*-equivalence of its category of representations, however as the above example shows, this auto-equivalence does not need to be isomorphic to the identity. However, if our interest is to investigate the general structure of that category, i.e. *all* (fin.-dim., complex) representations, this is kind of harmless. In a way, we only "shuffle them around".

[Actually, in the above example, which generalises to all $\mathfrak{sl}_{n \ge 3}$, the involution $F$, being "the" outer automorphism of the Lie algebra, on first sight seems to induce (up to ...) the duality functor on the category, i.e.: $$\rho \circ F \simeq \rho^* $$
However it is not actually the duality functor, because that one also flips arrows around (is contravariant), whereas the one defined as above via $F$ is covariant: They only do the same on objects. Now this estranged me at first, but I think is redeemed by the category also being semisimple (and duals commuting with direct sums), i.e. basically every arrow can be reversed.]

Comment: Another example: the triality outer automorphisms of $\mathrm{so}(8)$, which permute the vector and left/right spinor irreps (all inequivalent).

Comment: Thanks very much for your additional explanation!